# IE9 is ignoring X-UA-Compatible flag for UserAgent

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, user-agent, x-ua-compatible

I've an internet Application, so the IE9 is per default in the Compatibility View. I use the `X-UA-Compatible` flag. 
I sent it in the HTTP Header and as Meta-Tag.
IE9 seems to accept it and use the IE9 rendering engine. But its still always sending the IE-7 UserAgent string.

Is there any way to avoid it, or to identify this IE9 as a not IE7 browser?

I really dont want to use a whitelist of browsers, but a blacklist of not-supported browsers (IE 5, 6, 7 & 8).

My example:

I'm opening the page so the IE9 is sending an an GET request:

```
GET http://myserver/mypage/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg,     application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: de-CH
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: myserver
Cookie: MAKEBROWSERTEST=true
```

Then, my server is answering:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /myserver/mypage/two
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: MAKEBROWSERTEST=true; path=/
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2012 10:04:21 GMT
Content-Length: 152

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/myserver/mypage/two">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

The IE9 is redirecting, but still sending the MSIE 7.0 User Agent:

```
GET http://myserver/mypage/two HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: de-CH
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: myserver
Cookie: MAKEBROWSERTEST=true
```

Thanks

Comment: Actually IE renders the page according to the X-UA-Compatible setting. It just follow the order of its user by requestig an IE7 page but after receive the X-UA-Compatible it works as the tag asked. Jut try `JSON` in console (witch is not available in IE7 mode) and you will see that works.

Comment: Thats true! For the rendering it looks on the X-UA-Compatible setting, but not for the User-Agent String even when I sent the X-UA-compatible flag before. This does matter for me, because I want to make a 302 request depending on the Browser Version! Currently I see no way to do this!

Comment: Maybe you can make some assumptions based on the Trident version. Looks like it is consistent with the browser version.

Comment: If u have checked my question u would see that the user agent string is exactly the same before and after I sent the X-UA-Compatible flag! So also the trident version is identical!

Comment: If the site is already in compatibility view before you add the meta tag, then the user agent string CANNOT be forced out of compatibility view. The page will appear to be rendered in the modern browser, but in the background the agent string is still IE 7. [I blogged about this exact issue](http://frankcode.net/2013/10/17/a-guide-to-ie-compatibility-view-and-x-ua-compatible/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not trying to revive an old thread, but if anyone comes across this, they might find this interesting:
[Internet Explorer 11’s Many User-Agent Strings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx)

> If the user chooses to render a site in Compatibility View (click Tools > Compatibility View Settings) then IE will send a User-Agent string that **mimics Internet Explorer 7’s UA** string:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C)
```

By default, sites in the Intranet Zone render in Compatibility view, so this is the User-Agent string they’ll see.

So I did a test with IE9:

In (normal mode) you get

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
```

In compatibility mode you get

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
```